# Is there a way to achieve Autofailover and autodiscovery of redis nodes with JedisCluster?

Tags: redis, high-availability, jedis, redis-sentinel

I used Jedis Java client for Redis and it is fantastic.
I used separately the features for clustering (JedisCluster) and for High-Availability (JedisSentinelPool).

Both implementations work like a charm alone, however it doesn't seem to be a way to use both together.

I want to have High-Availability with automatic slave promotion on failover and autodiscovery of other masters when a master fails (like sentinel does).
I know Redis-cluster does automatic failover and that it also provides some kind of autodiscovery of the topology. But It seems that Jedis-Cluster does not provide any way to handle autofailover and take full advantage of Jedis cluster.

Is there any way to achieve autofailover with JedisClient?

Can I use JedisSentinel and JedisCluster together?

Some posts suggest that this is not possible: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jedis_redis/HtDblX771bs

Documentation on Jedis git is limited regarding this topic.